# Codelite Sample code Executable

Tags: codelite

I am just started exploring codelite. I have written a sample program hello.c to create a window and it will display "Hello World". Executable hello.exe is available under Debug directory. When i execute that from my system its working fine.

I have copied the hello.exe to my other system and tried to execute from there and i got error message "The Application was unable to start correctly. Clock OK to close the application".

Is it not possible to run the executable created in one PC to other PC? Do i need to any specific option during compilation?

Also i have installed MingW 64 bit and GTK 3.6.4 in the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some information in your report, for example: when the error dialog was shown, did it say which error code or why it failed to launch?

Did you try using dependency walker to check whether you are missing some DLLs that exist on your computer but *not* on the other PC?

If you are building using a MinGW-64, then try to use [dependency walker for 64 bit applications](http://www.dependencywalker.com/depends22_x64.zip) to see which DLLs are missing